# Is it recommended to use recursive algorithm to calculate sum of n cubes in terms of time and space efficiency?

Tags: performance, algorithm, recursion

Is it recommended to use recursive algorithm to calculate sum of n cubes in terms of time and space efficiency? comparing to a non-recursive?

Comment: If the cubes are consecutive, it is recommended to use the closed form. ( (n(n+1)/2)^2 )

Comment: It's always recommended to not use recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean? Summing the first n cubes is best done by computing (n^2*(n + 1)^2)/4, but if you're given a list of numbers to sum their cubes, that's not much of an option.

If you are in a language that does tail call optimization, a tail call recursive implementation is certainly recommended. If you're not, it may still be worth writing the recursive function if that is easier for you to reason about (a very important aspect of organizing code!). But do keep in mind that a recursion of depth n will take, depending on your language, compiler, etc., anywhere from 4*n to at least several 100*n bytes of memory, and stack space isn't unlimited.

I'd go for a loop in most languages. For large n, because it is more resource efficient, and for small n, because I find it easier to read than a recursive version. But that's tied to my personal background and experience, and what is easier for you and whoever else needs to se your code maybe completely different.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on what you want to accomplish. If you want it to be dependent on previous outcomes, you can make it recursive. Otherwise I would suggest to make it non-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Most **compiled** languages have **tail recursion** removal and **for simple case like this** it will **not be a problem**. Math people find it much easier to write functional languages and recursions come more natural to them. You can however you can write very efficiently:

```
var sumOf0To10Cubes = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(o => Math.Pow(o, 3)).Sum();
```

Note that math people prefer:

> [Sum[x^3,x->{0,10}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bx%5E3%2Cx-%3E%7B0%2C10%7D%5D)